# Cannot run android emulator - Unexpected error while creating: C (error: 3)

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-machine, adb, android-virtual-device

I have a problem running my avd on my windows device.

I created avds through the device manager of android studio.
[image: All my avds]

When I try to run one of the avds, I can see the process in the task manager, but not on desktop.
[image]

It is also not visible on "Running Devices" in Android Studio itself. ADB does also not recognize the newly started virtual device. The only indicator that a emulator is running is the instance in the task manager. If I try to run the avd through cmd, I get following error:

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 32.1.14.0 (build_id 10330179) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath C:\Users\eliaskadiri\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis\x86_64\
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\ELIASK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
ERROR   | Unexpected error while creating: C (error: 3)
```

I have to stop the method by ctrl + c, or it would result in a infinte loop throwing the last error.

I have no clue what could cause this issue. Virtualization is enabled, I have an AMD Ryzen processor (Windows 11) and this is my following Windows feature list:

[image]

I tried reinstalling

- Android Studio
- Android Emulator hypervisor driver
- Updating SDK-Buildtools and Platform-Tools

I tried to enable and disable hyper-v as well, but nothing really solved the issue.

I am thankful for every bit of help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a test I would try to run a recent non-GoogleAPI image, as those images are encrypted and protected to avoid modification. The non-GoogleAPI images are just plain images. Any may be looking into `emu-crash.db` would give more details?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I can try a non-GoogleAPI image. But where can I find them? Regarding the `emu-crash.db`. It is quite empty, the only file with more than 0kb is the settings.dat. Everything else is empty.

Comment: non-GoogleAPI images are also available in the Android Virtual Device manager. Just switch to the Tab "x86 Images" (by default it is "Recommended").

Comment: I tried launching the emulator with `Android 12.0 | x86_64`, but unfortunately, it still caused the same issue with the error loop. This Image was non-GoogleAPI

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and it helped to create an empty `.android` folder in the user directory of current user (i.e. `C:\Users\<Username>\.android`).
Not sure why and not sure if this has any side-effects, but the emulator was able to start again.